# How to get the total count of records in Angular? (Either from Subject or from Observable)

Tags: angular

I am still new to Angular.  However going through the examples on returning data from an API I now need to set a variable to display the total amount of records that were returned from the API.

How can I accomplish this (i.e. Set totalCount)?

Parameters:

```
  private mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<DataReference[]>([]);
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public totalCount: number;
```

I have this method:

```
loadData(findParams: MyParameters) {

    this.loadingSubject.next(true);

    this.myCustomService.getData(findParams)
      .pipe(
      //catchError(() => of([])),
      finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
      )
      .subscribe(x => this.mySubject.next(x));

    this.totalCount = ??;
  }
```

EDIT
This is the method being called in the service.

```
  getData(findParams: MyParameters): Observable<MyData[]> {

    return this.http
      .get<MyData[]>(this.API_URL + "", {
        params: this.SetParameters(findParams)
      })

      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Can you give example of what your data looks like and what your expected input/output are? [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added method from service that is being called.

Comment: do you just want the counts or is there a model you got?

Comment: MyData is currently a model that is used for a table.  I need to find the total count for pagination.  Since I'm still new I'm not sure if it should be done here or in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like that

```
subscribe(x => {
                this.totalCount = x.length;
                this.mySubject.next(x);
                });
```